# Liferay Community Edition centralized/shared storage issue

Tags: windows, tomcat, storage, liferay, cluster-computing

For quite some time I've been working on getting the community version of Liferay 6.0.6 (windows 2003 + Apache Httpd 2.2 + Apache Tomcat 6.0.29 ) to run on shared storage environment. Only the application base (webapps) is currently running from the shared storage. But I also wanted to move the "data" and "deploy" directory to the shared storage. So please provide any custom settings/changes that needs to be performed to change the location of these two directories/folders.

Whenever I change the "deploy destination directory" some portlets work, but not all (Custom portlets). It'll be great if anybody can provide certain points/checklist which needs to be followed in this situation.

Additionally, the configurations files used are attached along with this thread. If any other files is needed please let me know the same.

Thank you for your support in advance. All efforts are appreciated.

Thanks,
Joji VJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set Cache Page Definition Only at System Level,

By using this option create a single cached copy of the page definition in the system cache for all users.

Because the page definition is the same for all users, page customization options are disabled. This caching option greatly reduces storage requirements and improves performance.

Comment: Thank you Kelvin,
 Since we are looking for high availability solution, it'll be great if there is one.